# torchvision make_grid only displays top image

Tags: torch, torchvision

For some reason make_grid only displays the top image of the tensor **decoded_samples**. I can confirm that all of the decoded_samples have different values. 
Moreover, when an individual image is passed (eg. make_grid(decoded_samples[3]), it is properly displayed. 
Why is this happening?

```
samples = torch.randn(64, 32).to(device)
decoded_samples = model.decoder(samples).view(64,1,28,28)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))   
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(decoded_samples[:16], nrow=4, pad_value=1.)\
                .data.cpu().numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no discernible reason as to why this code doesn't work. Moving the code onto a Colab notebook produced the correct results...